# Error: Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap/lib/Breadcrumb'

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, breadcrumbs, truffle

I am following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/YPbgjPPC1d0 at 34:55 I am trying to use "truffle test", but keep getting Error: Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap/lib/Breadcrumb'

My code:

```js
const { should, assert } = require('chai')
const { useReducer } = require('react')
const { Item } = require('react-bootstrap/lib/Breadcrumb')

const color = artifacts.require('./color.sol')


require('Chair')
useReducer(require('chai-as-promised'))
should()

contract ('color', (accounts) => {
    describe('deployment', async () => {
        It('deploys successfully', async () => {
            contract = await color.deployed()
            const address = contract.address
            console.log(address)
            assert.notEqual(address, '')
        })
    })
})
```

I am using Virtual Studio Code

Has anyone had similar problem or know how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: It would be great if you can write in your post what the video talks about instead of just posting the link here.